# Laravel and Android with MySQL database

Tags: android, mysql, laravel

do you have any idea, experience, or links of any tutorial about how to connect Laravel with MySQL database to android application made using android studio? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Required Elements for That

> Tools :

**1. PhpStorm**

**2. PostMan**

**3. Android Studio**

> Working with Android

**You need to create api's for Database insertion, modification, deletion then Connect Api through [RetroFit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) then Just need to implement what you want**